# Some columns are not shown in Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write from java to excel.

[From this link here](http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-write-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi), the data are saved from Object Array. However, for my case, data are actually taken from 2 methods called NameGenerator to create a name and a method called PhoneGenerator to create a number. And save those values to excel, row by column. The results can be seen below.

> Peter   | 5124131
>
> Rock    | 24141
>
> Susan   | 067643

However the current code overwrites the name. As result the excel file looks like

> ```
>   | 5124131
>
>   | 24141
>
>   | 067643
> ```

Anyone willing to help me? Any inputs will be appreciate!

```html
try {
    
    //create excel
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
     "excelfile.xls");
   HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Register Data");

   DataGenerator dg = new DataGenerator();

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        //NameGenerator method will create random name
    String name = dg.NameGenerator;
        
        //PhoneGenerator method will create random phone
    String phone = dg.PhoneGenerator;

    worksheet.createRow(i).createCell(0).setCellValue(name);
    worksheet.createRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue(phone);

   }

      //save excel
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.flush();
   fileOut.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misused the `createRow(index)` method. You should call it once for each row, otherwise it will recreate what you had previously and all you had will be lost(hence you lose the first column).

Do it like this:

```
            ...
            HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(i);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(name);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(phone);
            ...
```

Comment: Glad it heIped. If answer solves your problem, generally, you accept it, and upvote it. :)

Comment: I accepted the answer. However, I cant upvote it due to my low reputation. Thanks for rephrasing my question to make it more understandable to other users!